# Grails application load script before require module

Tags: javascript, html, grails, config

i have some problem when script is loaded after require modules is there a way to make it load before require modules?

My app.gsp code :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=9" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My app</title>
    <g:render template="/myCommonJs" plugin="my-ext-js-common" />
    <r:require module="css"/>   
    <r:require module="utils"/>
    <r:require module="plugins"/>
    <r:require module="extensions"/>
    <r:require module="stores"/>
    <r:require module="ui"/>
    <g:if test="${currentEnvironment.toString().toLowerCase() != 'development'}">      
        <g:render template="/templates/headersProd" />
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
        <g:render template="/templates/headersDev" />
    </g:else>
    <r:layoutResources/>
    <script id='top-menu' parent='#main_container' src='//topbar.com/include.js' theme='blue'></script>
</head>
```

i want to make `top-menu` load before the modules.

Comment: try to put <script id='top-menu' parent='#main_container' src='//topbar.com/include.js' theme='blue'></script> before require modules.

Comment: this does not change anything

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try r:script tag in place of script tag this may resolve your problem.

Comment: when added script does not render at all